# Retrofit login with email and password

Tags: android, json, api, authentication, retrofit

I have a trouble with login. I tried several examples from net but nothing worked for me.

JSON

```
{
    "responseCode":1,
    "responseCodeText":"ok",
    "response":
    {
        "id":1234,
        "email":"test@test.cz",
        "name":"name",
        "lastname":"lastname",
        "properties":[
            //...
        ],
        "rights":"admin",
        "photo":"url",
        "favorites":
        [
            //...
        ],
        "token":"token"
    }
}
```

I have created **model class** from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ , so it should be OK.

**Interface**

```
public interface LoginInterface {

    @POST("login/{email}/{password}")
    Call<UserResponse> login(@Path("email") String email, @Path("password") String password);
}
```

**Call in activity**

```
public void serviceInit() {
        String email = edEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = edPassword.getText().toString();

        FactoryAPI.getInstanceLogin().login(email, password).enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AccountActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                //TODO: load from sharedPreferences
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", "points not loaded");
            }
        });
    }
```

**ERROR which I have**

> responseCodeText: "attribute error"

I got a request from server. My email and password are in GET, not in POST

Thanks for help

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: What kind of trouble you are facing ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the description of the error.

Comment: I added my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
Call<UserResponse> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response class that the json will be mapped into must have the exact structure and attributes as the json.

So your UserResponse should include **all** fields. Something like this:

```
public class UserResponseDTO {
  public int responseCode;
  public String responseCodeText;
  public UserDTO response;
}

public class UserDTO {
  public int id;
  public String email;
  public String name;
  public String lastname;
  public List<PropertyDTO> properties;
  public String rights;
  public String photo;
  public List<FavoriteDTO> favorites;
  public String token;
}
```

Comment: I found that problem was with `@FormUrlEncoded`. Is it possible? Thats what I added and now it is working.

Comment: So you're not specifying the endpoint like `@POST("login/{email}/{password}")`? 
Do you mind editing your post, with the working solution?